# Difference between abstract class and interface in Python

Tags: python, interface, abstract-class

What is the difference between abstract class and interface in Python?

Answer (score 687, accepted):

What you'll see sometimes is the following:

```py
class Abstract1:
    """Some description that tells you it's abstract,
    often listing the methods you're expected to supply."""

    def aMethod(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Should have implemented this")
```

Because Python doesn't have (and doesn't need) a formal Interface contract, the Java-style distinction between abstraction and interface doesn't exist.  If someone goes through the effort to define a formal interface, it will also be an abstract class.  The only differences would be in the stated intent in the docstring.

And the difference between abstract and interface is a hairsplitting thing when you have duck typing.

Java uses interfaces because it doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Because Python has multiple inheritance, you may also see something like this

```py
class SomeAbstraction:
    pass  # lots of stuff - but missing something

class Mixin1:
    def something(self):
        pass  # one implementation

class Mixin2:
    def something(self):
        pass  # another

class Concrete1(SomeAbstraction, Mixin1):
    pass

class Concrete2(SomeAbstraction, Mixin2):
    pass
```

This uses a kind of abstract superclass with mixins to create concrete subclasses that are disjoint.

Comment: S. Lott, do you mean that because of duck typing the distinction between has-a (interface) and is-a (inheritance) is not substantial?

Comment: The difference between abstract and interface is a hairsplitting thing when you have duck typing.  I don't know what "substantial" means.  It's "real" -- it has substance -- from a design perspective.  But from a language perspective there may be no support.  You could adopt conventions to distinguish between an abstract class and an interface class definition in Python.

Comment: @L.DeLeo - are you sure your notion of has-a vs. is-a is correct?  I generally view the distinction as has-a = member variable vs. is-a = inheritance (parent class *or* interface).  Think Comparable or List in Java; those are is-a relationships, regardless of whether they're interfaces or abstract classes.

Comment: `NotImplementedError("Class %s doesn't implement aMethod()" % (self.__class__.__name__))` is more informative error message :)

Comment: @Lorenzo a has-a relationship doesn't have anything to do with inheritance, duck typing, interfaces and abstract classes (all four refer to is-a relationships).

Comment: Python my not need a formal Interface contract but python isn't writing itself, _humans_ are. Interfaces are to help _humans_ write and share code. Computers want binary, humans want languages.

Answer (score 230):

> ## What is the difference between abstract class and interface in Python?

An interface, for an object, is a set of methods and attributes on that object.

In Python, we can use an abstract base class to define and enforce an interface.

### Using an Abstract Base Class

For example, say we want to use one of the abstract base classes from the `collections` module:

```
import collections
class MySet(collections.Set):
    pass
```

If we try to use it, we get an `TypeError` because the class we created does not support the expected behavior of sets:

```
>>> MySet()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MySet with abstract methods
__contains__, __iter__, __len__
```

So we are required to implement at *least* `__contains__`, `__iter__`, and  `__len__`. Let's use this implementation example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes):

```
class ListBasedSet(collections.Set):
    """Alternate set implementation favoring space over speed
    and not requiring the set elements to be hashable. 
    """
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.elements = lst = []
        for value in iterable:
            if value not in lst:
                lst.append(value)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.elements)
    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self.elements
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.elements)

s1 = ListBasedSet('abcdef')
s2 = ListBasedSet('defghi')
overlap = s1 & s2
```

### Implementation: Creating an Abstract Base Class

We can create our own Abstract Base Class by setting the metaclass to `abc.ABCMeta` and using the `abc.abstractmethod` decorator on relevant methods. The metaclass will be add the decorated functions to the `__abstractmethods__` attribute, preventing instantiation until those are defined.

```
import abc
```

For example, "effable" is defined as something that can be expressed in words. Say we wanted to define an abstract base class that is effable, in Python 2:

```
class Effable(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __str__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('users must define __str__ to use this base class')
```

Or in Python 3, with the slight change in metaclass declaration:

```
class Effable(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __str__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('users must define __str__ to use this base class')
```

Now if we try to create an effable object without implementing the interface:

```
class MyEffable(Effable): 
    pass
```

and attempt to instantiate it:

```
>>> MyEffable()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyEffable with abstract methods __str__
```

We are told that we haven't finished the job.

Now if we comply by providing the expected interface:

```
class MyEffable(Effable): 
    def __str__(self):
        return 'expressable!'
```

we are then able to use the concrete version of the class derived from the abstract one:

```
>>> me = MyEffable()
>>> print(me)
expressable!
```

There are other things we could do with this, like register virtual subclasses that already implement these interfaces, but I think that is beyond the scope of this question. The other methods demonstrated here would have to adapt this method using the `abc` module to do so, however.

### Conclusion

We have demonstrated that the creation of an Abstract Base Class defines interfaces for custom objects in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation!
Would you mind explaining the difference (if any) between `class Effable(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):` and `class Effable(abc.ABC):`?

Answer (score 103):

Python >= 2.6 has [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html).

> Abstract Base Classes (abbreviated
>   ABCs) complement duck-typing by
>   providing a way to define interfaces
>   when other techniques like hasattr()
>   would be clumsy. Python comes with
>   many builtin ABCs for data structures
>   (in the collections module), numbers
>   (in the numbers module), and streams
>   (in the io module). You can create
>   your own ABC with the abc module.

There is also the [Zope Interface](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface) module, which is used by projects outside of zope, like twisted. I'm not really familiar with it, but there's a wiki page [here](http://wiki.zope.org/Interfaces/FrontPage) that might help.

In general, you don't need the concept of abstract classes, or interfaces in python (edited - see S.Lott's answer for details).

Comment: What do you gain by using ABCs in Python?

Answer (score 51):

In a more basic way to explain:
An interface is sort of like an empty muffin pan.
It's a class file with a set of method definitions that have no code.

An abstract class is the same thing, but not all functions need to be empty. Some can have code. It's not strictly empty.

Why differentiate:
There's not much practical difference in Python, but on the planning level for a large project, it could be more common to talk about interfaces, since there's no code. Especially if you're working with Java programmers who are accustomed to the term.

Comment: +1 for the distinction where ABC can have implementations of their own - which seems a very cool way of outsmarting oneself

Answer (score 41):

Python doesn't really have either concept.

It uses [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4205130), which removed the need for interfaces (at least for the computer :-))

Python <= 2.5:
Base classes obviously exist, but there is no explicit way to mark a method as 'pure virtual', so the class isn't really abstract.

Python >= 2.6:
Abstract base classes do [exist](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) (http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). And allow you to specify methods that must be implemented in subclasses. I don't much like the syntax, but the feature is there. Most of the time it's probably better to use duck typing from the 'using' client side.

Comment: Python 3.0 does add real abstract base classes. They are used in the collections module as well as other places. http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/abc.html

Comment: A reference on why duck typing removes the need for interfaces would be helpful. It doesn't seem obvious to me that duck typing, which I understand as the ability to "poke" any method or attribute on any object, would mean that you don't need to specify required behaviors (and get the compiler to remind you to implement them), which is how I understand Abstract Base Classes.

Comment: It's less the duck typing then the support for multiple inheritence that removes the artificial line between interface and abstract class that e.g. Java has drawn.

Answer (score 21):

In general, interfaces are used only in languages that use the single-inheritance class model. In these single-inheritance languages, interfaces are typically used if any class could use a particular method or set of methods. Also in these single-inheritance languages, abstract classes are used to either have defined class variables in addition to none or more methods, or to exploit the single-inheritance model to limit the range of classes that could use a set of methods.

Languages that support the multiple-inheritance model tend to use only classes or abstract base classes and not interfaces.  Since Python supports multiple inheritance, it does not use interfaces and you would want to use base classes or abstract base classes.

http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html

Answer (score 4):

Abstract classes are classes that contain one or more abstract methods. Along with abstract methods, Abstract classes can have static, class and instance methods.
But in case of interface, it will only have abstract methods not other. Hence it is not compulsory to inherit abstract class but it is compulsory to inherit interface.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, we should mention [PEP3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#abcs-vs-interfaces)
where ABC was introduced and compared with interfaces,
and original [Talin's](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-April/006614.html) comment.

The abstract class is not perfect interface:

- belongs to the inheritance hierarchy
- is mutable

But if you consider writing it your own way:

```
def some_function(self):
     raise NotImplementedError()

interface = type(
    'your_interface', (object,),
    {'extra_func': some_function,
     '__slots__': ['extra_func', ...]
     ...
     '__instancecheck__': your_instance_checker,
     '__subclasscheck__': your_subclass_checker
     ...
    }
)

ok, rather as a class
or as a metaclass
and fighting with python to achieve the immutable object
and doing refactoring
...
```

you'll quite fast realize that you're inventing the wheel
to eventually achieve
`abc.ABCMeta`

`abc.ABCMeta` was proposed as a useful addition of the missing interface functionality,
and that's fair enough in a language like python.

Certainly, it was able to be enhanced better whilst writing version 3, and adding new syntax and immutable interface concept ...

Conclusion:

```
The abc.ABCMeta IS "pythonic" interface in python
```