# Can one declare an abstract exception in Python?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

I would like to declare a hierarchy of user-defined exceptions in Python.  However, I would like my top-level user-defined class (`TransactionException`) to be abstract.  That is, I intend `TransactionException` to specify methods that its subclasses are required to define.  However, `TransactionException` should never be instantiated or raised.

I have the following code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class TransactionException(Exception):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def displayErrorMessage(self):
        pass
```

However, the above code allows me to instantiate `TransactionException`...

```
a = TransactionException()
```

In this case `a` is meaningless, and should instead draw an exception.  The following code removes the fact that `TransactionException` is a subclass of `Exception`...

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class TransactionException():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def displayErrorMessage(self):
        pass
```

This code properly prohibits instantiation but now I cannot raise a subclass of `TransactionException` because it's not an `Exception` any longer.

Can one define an abstract exception in Python?  If so, how? If not, why not?

NOTE: I'm using Python 2.7, but will happily accept an answer for Python 2.x or Python 3.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a great answer on this topic by Alex Martelli [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2862419/716118). In essence, it comes down how the object initializers (`__init__`) of the various base classes (`object`, `list`, and, I presume, `Exception`) behave when abstract methods are present.

When an abstract class inherits from `object` (which is the default, if no other base class is given), its `__init__` method is set to that of `object`'s, which performs the heavy-lifting in checking if all abstract methods have been implemented.

If the abstract class inherits from a different base class, it will get that class' `__init__` method. Other classes, such as `list` and `Exception`, it seems, **do not check for abstract method implementation**, which is why instantiating them is allowed.

The other answer provides a suggested workaround for this. Of course, another option that you have is simply to accept that the abstract class will be instantiable, and try to discourage it.

Answer (score 2):

```
class TransactionException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError('you should not be raising this')


class EverythingLostException(TransactionException):

    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(TransactionException, self).__init__(msg)


try:
    raise EverythingLostException('we are doomed!')
except TransactionException:
    print 'check'

try:
    raise TransactionException('we are doomed!')
except TransactionException:
    print 'oops'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can still instantiate `TransactionException`, you just can't initialize it (`exc = TransactionException.__new__(TransactionException)`). But this is probably in the spirit of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation for an abstract exception class, in which the children of the class work out of the box.

```py
class TransactionException(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        self._check_abstract_initialization(self)

    @staticmethod
    def _check_abstract_initialization(self):
        if type(self) == TransactionException:
            raise NotImplementedError("TransactionException should not be instantiated directly")


class AnotherException(TransactionException):
    pass


TransactionException() # NotImplementedError: TransactionException should not be instantiated directly

AnotherException # passes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helper function that can be used in such scenario:

```py
def validate_abstract_methods(obj):
    abstract_methods = []
    for name in dir(obj):
        value = getattr(obj, name, None)
        if value is not None and getattr(value, '__isabstractmethod__', False):
            abstract_methods.append(name)
    if abstract_methods:
        abstract_methods.sort()
        raise TypeError(f"Can't instantiate abstract class {obj.__class__.__name__} with abstract methods {', '.join(abstract_methods)}")
```

This function roughly does the same thing as `abc.ABC` class - you just need to call it from your class' `__init__` method.