# Python3.8 typing Protocol: Anything standard for adapter registries?

Tags: interface, adapter, python-3.8, zope.interface

The zope.interface has (among many other things) run-time adapter registries, which allow to find suitable implementations of some interface at run-time.

Now, the python3.8 has [structural subtyping support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), but the question is: Are there any standard library mechanisms to achieve at least some primitive run-time adaptation out-of-the box? In other words, having some instance `animal` and an interface `IFlying`, is it possible to lookup an adapter for `IFlying(animal)`? Or is the `typing.Protocol` purely for typechecking?

The motivation of this question is: Does it make sense to continue using `zope.interface` in the new code, or will typing.Protocol make that obsolete soon (at least for simple adapter cases)?

I can see opinions like [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41683), which hint that some standard interface support is there, but can't find concrete examples on how to replace adapter registry with Python3.8 or more recent standard library (short of writing some library on top of it).

Note: I am aware of [What to use in replacement of an interface/protocol in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022766/what-to-use-in-replacement-of-an-interface-protocol-in-python) , but my question is specifically about how to make adaptation (and even multiadapters) possible.