# Python - Specify parent or interface as return type

Tags: python, return-type

I am new to Python, and trying to understand how we can achieve something like below in python like  we do in Java.

```
public interface IParent {
}

public Class Parent1 implements IParent{
}

public Class Parent2 implements IParent{
}

Now, I can use like:

IParent p1 = new Parent1();
IParent p2 = new Parent2();
```

So, trying to understand how we can achieve this in Python. Seen some SO articles with TypeVar("T") but couldn't understand. or How we can know what's the return type of any class.

Appreciate any light here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to use in replacement of an interface/protocol in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022766/what-to-use-in-replacement-of-an-interface-protocol-in-python)

Comment: Keep in mind that everything in python is object-oriented and you rely on "duck-typing" to inform users that it is an interface. https://realpython.com/python-interface/

Comment: There seem to be at least two different questions here: how to simulate interface implementation (use inheritance), and how to restrict what can be assigned to `p1` and `p2` (which itself can be split into enforcing it at compile time and enforcing it at run time).

Comment: "How can we know what's the return type of any class?" In general, it's the class itself, *but* the `__new__` method of a class can be overridden to return something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python there is no such thing as interfaces. Instead, use inheritance and so-called abstract base classes (ABC), which, to put it simply, are classes that cannot be instantiated. Your code would translate to:

```
from abc import ABC

class IParent(ABC):
    pass

class Parent1(IParent):
    pass

class Parent2(IParent):
    pass


p1 = Parent1()
p2 = Parent2()
```

Please refer to [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/abstract-classes-in-python/) for a more detailed explanation.