# Is there a way to simulate Java's "Interface" in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to predefine a method that must be implemented should the model be extended. Is there a way to enforce this in Odoo? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need them, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181576/java-abstract-interface-design-in-python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own view implementation or you need to use qweb engine which will allow you to embed the iframes and applets, which will help simulate java code over Odoo pages

Bests