# `pass` keyword to mark end of indented code block

Tags: python, coding-style

I have recently noticed that some people mark the end of indented code blocks with the `pass` keyword, such as:

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        do_something(i)
        pass
    pass
```

I don't understand why. Are there any advantages?

I know the `pass` keyword does nothing and it is the equivalent of `{ }` in other languages. My question is more related to a convention. For example, maybe people like to have something marking the end of a long code block.

Comment: the pass in your snippet doesn't ve any adv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you think Python's indention-sensitive grammar is harmful?

If your answer is **"no"**,
then using `pass` to mark an end does nothing but clutter the **cleanness**
brought in by Python's indention sensitive grammar.

If your answer is **"yes"**,
then using `pass` to mark an end is a workaround for the **ambiguity**
brought in by Python's indention sensitive grammar.

In Python, there is no `{}` and `end`, but semantic white spaces.

For example, consider the following Ruby code:

```
def f
    for i in 0...10
        i = i * 2
        print(i)
    end
end
```

And the equivalent Python code:

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        i = i * 2
        print(i)
```

With one wrong keystroke (`TAB`):

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        i = i * 2
    print(i)
```

The above code is also valid.

To avoid this kind of mistakes, we can use `pass` for `end` in Python:

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        i = i * 2
        print(i)
        pass
    pass
```

With one wrong keystroke (`TAB`):

```
def f():
    for i in range(10):
        i = i * 2
    print(i)
        pass
    pass
```

Python will refuse to work:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

However, python will not always catch unintended indentation even with `pass`.

Suppose we intend to write:

```
def g():
    for i in range(10):
        i = i * 2
        pass
    print(i)
    pass
```

With one wrong keystroke (`TAB`):

```
def g():
    for i in range(10):
        i = i * 2
        pass
        print(i)
    pass
```

Python will *not* refuse to work.

But using `pass` still has two advantages:

- It still provides visual hint.

  If you think `pass` as the last clause of an indented block,
  `print(i)` looks weird to you in the above code.
- A decent editor/IDE will indent correctly if you typed `pass`.

For the second `pass`,
if `f()` is a top-level function,
and your code adheres to PEP8:

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.

You may omit the second `pass`.

But PEP8 also said:

> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly)
>   to separate groups of related functions.

Thus I prefer `pass`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any advantages?

No.

Placing `pass` at the end of non-empty code blocks like that just wastes lines.  Remember that `pass` is a do-nothing placeholder in Python; it should only be used when you need to fill in an empty code block.

If you would like some examples of when to use `pass`, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13886168/2555451) as well as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22414023/2555451).

Answer (score 2):

There is no advantage. If the function has a body at all, adding `pass` does nothing. It doesn't even do anything if there is *no* body, except to help the parser know that the empty body was intentional.

In real-world code, it's usually better to use a docstring than `pass` to denote deliberately-empty code:

```
class MyExtraException(Exception):
    """Just another exception"""
```