# What does "i" represent in Python .pyi extension?

Tags: python

In Python, what does "i" represent in `.pyi` extension?

In [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), it mentions `.pyi` is "a stub file" but no mnemonic help on the extension. So does the "i" mean "Include"? "Implementation"? "Interface"?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

I think the `i` in `.pyi` stands for "Interface"

Definition for Interface in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)):

> An interface in the Java programming language is an abstract type that
>   is used to specify a behaviour that classes must implement

- From Python [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed#format) github repository:

> Each Python module is represented by a `.pyi` "stub". This is a normal
>   Python file (i.e., it can be interpreted by Python 3), **except all the
>   methods are empty**.

- In ['Mypy'](https://github.com/python/mypy/wiki/Creating-Stubs-For-Python-Modules) repository, they explicitly mention "stub" files as public interfaces:

> A stubs file only contains a description of the **public interface** of
>   the module without any implementations.

Because "Interfaces" do not exist in Python (see this [SO question between Abstract class and Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372042/difference-between-abstract-class-and-interface-in-python)) I think the designers intended to dedicate a special extension for it.

`pyi` implements "stub" file (definition from [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html))

> **Stubs**: provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually
>   not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in for the
>   test.

But people are more familiar with Interfaces than "stub" files, therefore it was easier to choose `.pyi` rather than `.pys` to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Do the methods have to be empty? or can the be some reference implementation?

Comment: ‘I think the i in .pyi stands for "Interface". Definition for Interface in Java’ — why bring up a completely unrelated language that uses the term differently?

Comment: You're bringing up completely unrelated terms. Java interface is Java's way to multiple inheritance. Stub is simplified but working implementation used to speed up automated tests (eg in-memory database).

Answer (score 61):

The `i` in `.pyi` stands for ‘interface’.

The `.pyi` extension was first mentioned in [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/345) where JukkaL says:

> I'd probably prefer an extension with just a single dot. It also needs to be something that is not in use (it should not be used by cython, etc.). .pys seems to be used in Windows (or was). **Maybe .pyi, where i stands for an interface definition?**

Comment: Excellent reference! This supports the notion `.pyi` was first born from within the mypy project then more broadly adapted after discussions with in this thread https://github.com/python/typing/issues/22

Answer (score 40):

Apparently PyCharm creates .pyi file for its own purposes:

> The *.pyi files are used by PyCharm and other development tools to provide
>       more information, such as PEP 484 type hints, than it is able to glean from
>       introspection of extension types and methods.  They are not intended to be
>       imported, executed or used for any other purpose other than providing info
>       to the tools. If you don't use use a tool that makes use of .pyi files then
>       you can safely ignore this file.
>
> See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/
>            https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

This comment was found in: `python27/Lib/site-packages/wx/core.pyi`

Comment: Great info. Does it give a definitive answer to what the “i” in “pyi” stands for?

Comment: I didn't see one.  How about 'introspection'?  (I was just trying to understand what the file was)

Comment: @ChrisFreeman it says actually in 2nd ref (by PyCharm) literally next 

"PyCharm supports Python stub files with the .pyi extension. These files allow you to specify the type hints using Python 3 syntax for both Python 2 and 3.

The stub files are created as usual , but you must specify the extension .pyi explicitly."

Answer (score 1):

Another way to explain the contents of a module that Wing can't figure out is with a pyi Python Interface file. This file is merely a Python skeleton with the proper structure, call signature, and return values to correspond to the functions, attributes, classes, and methods specified in a module.

Comment: How does this answer the question of what does ‘i’ stand for?