# What does "..." means in a python def

Tags: python, function, overriding

This might be a very stupid question but I can't understand what the three dots stands for in a python `def`. I was trying to comprehend the cost of the `in` operator in a `deque` object (from the `collections` module), so I navigated through the code and here's what I found:

[image: img]

I thought they mean the method will use the "upper" definition when called, but if I navigate to the overridden method I can't find nothing if not an abstract method in the `Container` class.. so I still don't get how the `in` operator works on a `deque` object.

Comment: About "..." and .pyi file, refer to [stackoverflow.com/q/41734836](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734836/what-does-i-represent-in-python-pyi-extension)

Comment: @RegisterSole There's nothing about `...` in that question.

Comment: @Barmar Based on the answer there, a .pyi file describes the interface of the module **without** any implementation. Hence, `...` really means ... in ordinary text. That is, the part of the text is deliberately omitted as it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a .pyi stub file. Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734836/what-does-i-represent-in-python-pyi-extension), a stub file, as the name suggests, is only meant to describe the interface and not the implementation inside. Hence, `...` in a Python def really means that this file is just a def and you cannot find the implementation here.

Regarding your question about the cost of `in` operator in `deque`, refer to https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

It mentions `deque` is represented internally as a doubly-linked list, and also mentions that `in` operator for a `list` has O(n) complexity. I don't think it being a doubly-linked list changes the time complexity, as you would still need to go through each element, i.e., O(n).