# Type annotations with .pyi file in PyCharm doesn't work for dynamic attributes

Tags: python, pycharm

My goal is to have autocomplete in the Pycharm Editor (in Python Console it works fine) for arguments used by `pytransition` module. (Some background info about the module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60195188/no-suggestions-for-triggers-when-using-pytransitions))

The idea is to use the recipe mentioned [on PyCharm forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000665110/comments/115000541424) in regard to dynamic code: related `pyi` stub file with type annotations for the class.

That works well if I define the attribute like this:

```py
# class.pyi
class Model(object):
    evaporate = None
```

`# class.py`

[image]

But that doesn't work if I try to define the attributes dynamically, in the manner [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265479/9736648):

```py
# class.pyi
class Model(object):
    for x in ['ionize', 'melt']:
        locals()[x] = None
```

[image]

What could be the reason and how to overcome that?

Comment: Annotations are inherently static. Defining them dynamically is a contradiction. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken about the terminology, I'd like to have a way to pass attributes as a static list in a pyi file as to obtain typing insights when I use the instance of that class in the py file

Comment: You can already statically "list" attributes on a class, using regular attribute syntax. Why do you want to imperatively iterate an actual list to imperatively build these attributes? If the list is static, you can just as well write the same as a static declaration.

Comment: I already have names of attributes as a list, i.e. `["attr1", "attr2", "attrX"]` Do you mean that there's no more efficient way than to parse this list manually and have a line for each declaration, i.e. `attr1 = None` ?

Comment: You can write a script that formats the list to the appropriate source code. Doing so dynamically inside a ``pyi`` won't work.