# Python "socket" library - where is real implementation?

Tags: python, sockets, design-patterns

When i searched implementation of listen method in `_socket.pyi` i founded only this code with ellipsis:

```
class socket:
    # ... some another methods with ellipsis ...
    def listen(self, __backlog: int = ...) -> None: ...
```

I could not find a real implementation of `listen()`. What is this pattern when methods without explicit implementation are used in the main class of the module? What is the point of this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here - explanation what the ... mean  - or where the real implementation is? The first is answered by the duplicate. The latter - see [socketmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8b24d60f1b7725d526ea5b5d3904b72e8b41ae0d/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3560)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich understand how to work ellipsis, but i cant found real implementation of listen() method.  Why used this pattern?

Comment: Modules with performance requirements are usually implemented in C language. You only view a [`.pyi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734836/what-does-i-represent-in-python-pyi-extension) file, which is used for type hints.