# Is there some thing in python language which is similar to interface in Java or C++ as well?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I've used to program use Java or C++, both has the 'interface' mechanism. And in some books of Object Oriented Programming and Design Pattern, interface is often mentioned.

Is there anything similar to interface in Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124190/how-do-i-implement-interfaces-in-python

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372042/difference-between-abstract-class-and-interface-in-python

Comment: thanks! that is helpful